# How to display a full written program using printf?

Tags: c, printf

My assignment is to display a program using printf. my solution is to go through every line with quotes. but im stuck when i compile it wants me to declare "d"

I am facing an error to print this entire program. it wants me to define "d"
Please help me on this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

printf(
"/* This program reads two integers from the keyboard and prints their product."
"Written by: A Katheravan"
"Date : 10/02/2012"
"*/"

"#include <stdio.h>"
"int main (void)"

"{"
"//Local Definitions"

"int number1;"
"int number2;"
"int result;"

"//Statements"

"scanf("%d", &number1);"
"scanf ("%d", &number2);"
"result = number1 * number2;"
"printf("%d", result);"
"return 0;"

"}"
"//main");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The homework tag is [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: How about opening the `.c` file and copying it to the console?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a program that prints the text you have above? Or are you asking how to make a program that prints itself?

Comment: I am asking how to print the text above.

Comment: Its supposed to be very simple and the following answers are very simple So stop complaining and instead of asking homework question directly here. Follow the text book first.

Comment: i have tried various methods such as " " every line

Comment: You have completely changed your question. This now looks like an (incorrect) *answer* to the original question. I have voted to close due to lack of clarity.

Comment: I have editted it again. please help me on this. im super lost and my teacher is not very clear. this is an extra assignment. fyi i just started C

Comment: Kexy, stop changing your *question* into an attempt to *solve* it ... doing that is confusing and makes no sense.

Comment: Kexy, I already solved your problem below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, based on some hard thinking about what you're trying to get, I finally think you want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    printf(
        "/* This program reads two integers from the keyboard and prints their product.\n"
        "Written by: A Katheravan\n"
        "Date : 10/02/2012\n"
        "*/\n\n"

        "#include <stdio.h>\n\n"

        "int main (void)\n"
        "{\n"
        "\t//Local Definitions\n\n"

        "\tint number1;\n"
        "\tint number2;\n"
        "\tint result;\n\n"

        "\t//Statements\n\n"

        "\tscanf(\"%%d\", &number1);\n"
        "\tscanf (\"%%d\", &number2);\n"
        "\tresult = number1 * number2;\n"
        "\tprintf(\"%%d\", result);\n"
        "\treturn 0;\n\n"

        "}\n"
        "//main\n"
    );

    return 0;
}
```

To print `"` inside strings, you need to escape it: `\"`, that was your problem inside the strings.

I've also included the line breaks and tabs on each line, so the code doesn't get printed out in just one line on the console.

Also, to print `%` on `printf`, you got to use `%%`, because you'll learn later that `%` is reserved for formatting the string.

`\n` is "new line", and `\t` is "TAB", FYI.

Comment: I didn't think it was very hard. The OP asked how to print some text, and gave the text. For some bizarre reason, several people took it as a request for a program that prints itself. Unfortunately, your attempt has undefined behavior; try compiling it with gcc -Wall.

Comment: @JimBalter Yes, I didn't either, I was just joking about all the criticism.

Comment: @KexyKathe This program will not work ... go ahead and try it. Notice the small but important difference between it and my solution.

Comment: @JimBalter Yes it will. I compiled it on bcc32, MSVC, TCC (all on Windows) and GCC (on Linux and MinGW), and it also prints the exact output.

Comment: 'it also prints the exact output.' -- Only **after** you edited it to change the % to %%. Sheesh.

Comment: The edit was way before your comment... (edit: 05:55:37Z, your comment: 06:01:42Z)

Answer (score 2):

The following may be useful to you:

```
FILE * fp = fopen("program.c", "r");  

char c;
while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)   
    printf("%c", c);

fclose(fp);
```

Comment: sorry that is too complicated. it is supposed to be a very simple thing. very very basic.

Comment: @KexyKathe: You want a C program that prints itself that is less complicated than this?

Comment: Sorry i think i did not phrase it correctly. i want the text to be displayed using the function printf

Comment: @KexyKathe This snippet does use `printf()`...

Comment: @dreamlax The OP did not ask for a program that prints itself. We can provide better answers here at SO if we pay careful attention to what folks -- especially beginners -- ask.

Comment: @grijesh. Thanks. Here idea is to write the program inside the file. And write a program to print that file. Yes this is the simple way!!!

Comment: Yes, printing complete text-fill within single printf is wrong too..printf use some max-buffer-size

Answer (score 0):

Those type of programs which produce there own source code as output are called as "Quines".

According to Wikipedia Quines are

"A quine is a computer program which takes no input and produces a copy of its own source code as its only output"

Check out examples and complete explanation [Quines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29)

Here is the classic C Quine

```
char*f="char*f=%c%s%c;
main()
     {
printf(f,34,f,34,10);
}%c";
     main(){printf(f,34,f,34,10);}
```

Comment: Sorry i think i did not phrase it correctly. i want the text to be displayed using the function printf –

Comment: Do you mean you want to print the whole source code using printf in your program ?

Comment: Write program that displays PROGRAM, page 10 to the screen (using printf). that is my assignment. the program is the one above.

Comment: The question does not ask about a program printing its own source code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s",
       "#include <stdio.h>\n"
       "\n"
       "int main (void)\n"
       "\n"
       "{\n"
       "\n"
       "//Local Definitions\n"
       "\n"
       "int n1;\n"
       "int n2;\n"
       "int result;\n"
       "\n"
       "//Statements\n"
       "\n"
       "scanf(\"%d\", &n1);\n"
       "scanf (\"%d\" , &n2);\n"
       "result = n1 * n2;\n"
       "printf(\"%d\", result);\n"
       "return 0;\n"
       "\n"
       "}\n"
       "//main\n");

   return 0;
}
```

This probably isn't quite right, because the OP didn't format the code when posting it. Insert spaces and/or tabs to get the desired indentation.

Edit: This was an answer to the original question, but the OP has changed the question into an (erroneous) attempt to answer the question.

Comment: true. but i cant use string[] as i have no learnt it yet.

Comment: Fine, I've edited it not to use it.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems i've got to add the extra % so that it'll be printed. I am really grateful for your help. God bless have a nice day.